# UI5 - Routing with http header parameter

Tags: spring-security, jwt, sapui5

I have developed a small UI5 application with OData calls and I am implementing the authorizations. On the server I have a spring web security application where have I have restricted the MemebersList.view.xml to users that are logged in. My idea is to create under the folders view and controller a folder user for the logged in users with the files that are restricted.

After the user is successfully logged in I receive the token to make further OData calls.

**Question 1:**
Can I restrict in UI5 the resources(XML views and JS controllers) so that the user only has direct access when is logged in or the sources have to be visible allways? For example I want to avoid that the user can directly enter
http://localhost:9004/webapp/view/user/MembersList.view.xml or
http://localhost:9004/webapp/controller/user/MembersList.controllers.js and see the code

**Question 2:**
Can I somehow send the Token in the header when I call the view MembersList with the getRouter().navTo('MembersList')? I guess in this case I would also need somehow to pass the token to the call for the MembersList.controllers.js. Maybe set that all the http calls include the token?

Maybe there is a better approach

[image]

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/**/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.json",
                        "/**/*.xml",
                        "/**/*.properties",
                        "/**/*.woff2",
                        "/**/*.woff",
                        "/**/*.ttf",
                        "/**/*.ttc",
                        "/**/*.ico",
                        "/**/*.bmp",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.jpeg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js",
                        "/**/*.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

onClickEvent:

```
onLoginTap : function() {

            var navigator_info = window.navigator;
            var screen_info = window.screen;
            var uid = navigator_info.mimeTypes.length;
            uid += navigator_info.userAgent.replace(/\D+/g, '');
            uid += navigator_info.plugins.length;
            uid += screen_info.height || '';
            uid += screen_info.width || '';
            uid += screen_info.pixelDepth || '';

            this.loginBody.getData().email = this.login.getData().user;
            this.loginBody.getData().password = this.login.getData().password;
            this.loginBody.getData().deviceId = uid;

            // create XHR object
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var that = this;
            // gets everytime fired when the XHR request state changes
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                // 4 means request is finished and response is ready
                // 200 means request is just fine
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    // "this" refers here to the XHR object
                    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
                    if (json.accessToken !== null) {
                        that.login.getData().accessToken = json.accessToken;
                        that.getRouter().navTo("MembersList");
                    }
                }
            };

            // set the XHR request parameters
            xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:9004/api/auth/login", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // fire the XHR request
            xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(this.loginBody.getData()));
        }
```

Comment: Idea: Store the token in a global JSONModel. When routing, the target view can read the token from the model. if it's available show page, else redirect to some "you have to login".

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for you reply. That would work but in that case unlogged users would still have access to the resources. I have updated the question to be more specific with my problem.

Comment: Does this also mean that you don't *build* the application? Because the `Component-preload.js` would contain every view and controller anyway.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't restrict access to a resource like you want. Of course you could save the directory via e.g. htaccess/basic auth and the authorization username/pw you can call a webservice where you can make a user check from your spring security if the user is authorized to receive the basic auth data for the view/controller folder

Comment: Yes,I wanted to do it without Component-preload.js.

Comment: Thanks DubZ, I will check that possibility. I still don't know what it means but I will research it :D

Comment: You should be using Component-preload. There are reasons, why it is there. If you want to restrict access in a way that one part is accessible by some users, other part is accessible by other users, you should put it in two different Componets / Apps

Comment: Thanks for the tip iPirat. I will go for that solution.